# Edabit task doesn't show correct result

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, eval

I'm doing a simple task which requires to sort a list by expression result and running this code:

```
   def sort_by_answer(lst):
        ans = []
        dict = {}
        for i in lst:
            if 'x' in i:
                i = i.replace('x', '*')
            dict.update({i: eval(i)})
        dict = {k: v for k, v in sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}
        res = list(dict.keys())
        for i in res:
            if '*' in i:
                i = i.replace('*', 'x')
                ans.append(i)
            else:
                ans.append(i)
        return ans
```

It checks out but the site for which i'm doing this test(here's a link to the task(https://edabit.com/challenge/9zf6scCreprSaQAPq) tells my that my list is not correctly sorted, which it is, can someone help me improve this code or smth so it works in every case-scenario?

P.S.

```
if 'x' in i:
      i = i.replace('x', '*')
```

This is made so i can use the eval function but the site input has 'x' instead of '*' in their lists..

Comment: That's because `i=i.replace('x','*')` doesn't modify the value in the list.

Comment: @Ch3steR `i` here is a `str` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @SayandipDutta Try this. `a=['1 + 1', '1 + 7', '1 + 5', '1 + 4']; for i in a: i.replace('+','@')` now `print(a)` output is `['1 + 1', '1 + 7', '1 + 5', '1 + 4']`.

Comment: `sort_by_answer(['1 + 1', '1 + 7', '1 + 5', '1 + 4']) ➞['1 + 1', '1 + 4', '1 + 5', '1 + 7']`

This is the input and required output so yes `i` is a `str`

Comment: @SayandipDutta `str`'s are immutable. Let's say we a list `a=['1 + 1', '1 + 7', '1 + 5', '1 + 4'];for idx,v in enumerate(a):print(id(v),id(a[i]))` will print same ids but when you do `i=i.replace('+','@')` now `i` is pointing to new str object produced by `.replace`.

Comment: @SayandipDutta `.replace` doesn't mutate string in-place it produces a new string. Hope this clears everything.

Comment: @Ch3steR you overlooked something, the `i` here are elements of the list, which are string, it is of the sort: `for string in list: for char in string: string = string.replace(char, other_char)`, here `i` is in the inner loop.
And for the new string part, he is capturing the new string back again in `i` and using `i` to either update the dict, or append to the list.

Comment: @SayandipDutta Yeah, I just skimmed through the code. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. But using `eval` is dangerous on untrusted strings.

```
In [63]: a=['1 + 1', '1 + 7', '1 + 5', '1 + 4']

In [69]: def evaluate(_str):
    ...:     return eval(_str.replace('x','*'))
```

---

output

```
In [70]: sorted(a,key=evaluate)
Out[70]: ['1 + 1', '1 + 4', '1 + 5', '1 + 7']

In [71]: sorted(['4 - 4', '2 - 2', '5 - 5', '10 - 10'],key=evaluate)
Out[71]: ['4 - 4', '2 - 2', '5 - 5', '10 - 10']

In [72]: sorted(['2 + 2', '2 - 2', '2 x 1'],key=evaluate)
Out[72]: ['2 - 2', '2 x 1', '2 + 2']
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is an issue with your code, probably they are using something older that `3.6` and it is messing up the order of the dict. A tuple would be safer.

```
def sort_by_answer(lst):
    string = ','.join(lst).replace('x','*')
    l = string.split(',')
    d = [(k.replace('*','x'), eval(k)) for k in l]
    ans = [expr for expr, value in sorted(d, key = lambda x: x[1])]
    return ans
```

[image]

**EDIT**:
[@Ch3steR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60296792/5431791) is more *pythonic*:

```
def sort_by_answer(lst):
    return sorted(lst, key= lambda x: eval(x.replace('x','*')))
```

Comment: Thanks for the credits, means a lot :D . But I really don't want anyone to use `eval` on untrusted strings instead parsing the string to get actual output is really good practice. I'm sure everyone agrees on this.

Comment: Completely agreed.